# Delete file if it exists anywhere on the windows Device

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, scripting

[image]

I Am trying to delete a file which exists in like many folders which are dynamically created and I have no clue how and where to start. What would be the best approach using scripting to delete this file ?

Comment: To find them on the current drive, you could start with `Where /R \ googledrivesync.exe`…If you wanted to delete something, you could take a look at `Del /?`, which has a `/S` option.

Comment: ...or with `del /?` - there is a `/s` switch to process all subfolders:`del /s c:\googledrivesync.exe` - it may take a while to scan the folder tree.

Comment: Thanks it worked. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`del` has a `/s` switch to process all subfolders:

```
del /s c:\googledrivesync.exe
```

it may take a while to scan the folder tree. Get yourself a cup of coffee...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to delete *specific* files in a directory structure (as opposed to just deleting everything), from PowerShell, you could do

```
dir -recurse -file -filter nameOfFileToRemove rootDirectory | remove-item
```

This will recurse through the file tree, looking for *files* matching `nameOfFileToRemove` and then removing them. Also `nameOfFileToRemove` may contain wildcard characters like `"nameOfFile*.txt"`

Comment: Bruce, because of the simplicity of the `cmd.exe` based solution from @Stephan, could you please explain what benefits `powershell.exe` brings to this task.

Comment: PowerShell is a much more general solution. Suppose you want to include or exclude filename patterns, or select objects by one or more date ranges? PowerShell is a more flexible choice once your needs go beyond the constraints of the cmd.exe `del` command.